# Как исправить проблему с сумматорами?

Tags: нейронные-сети

скажите пожалуйста, что делать в следующей ситуации, когда сумма произведений на нейроне больше 1? Пропускать 1.2 через функцию активации, чтобы сумма принадлежала промежутку -1..1 ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А функция активации у вас какая? Все ж зависит от задачи. Если у вас, допустим, пороговая функция, где промежутку [0.8;1], допустим, соответствует некий ответ В. А все, что выше 1 - ответом не является, то ничего плохого в вашем варианте нет. И вообще, это на каком шаге у вас происходит? Первая эпоха, процесс обучения или уже работа обученной сети?

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev Гиперболический тангенс (th)

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev Ну как сказать, какой процесс, у меня генетический алгоритм используется для "подгона" весов под нужную задачу и сейчас у меня определяется на сколько хорошо инциализированны весы